# Error context in error handling in Scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, either

Suppose I need to call a remote JSON/HTTP service. I make a JSON request, send it by HTTP to the server, and receive and parse the JSON response.

Suppose I have data type `MyError`for errors and all my functions return `Either[MyError, R]`

```
type Result[A] = Either[MyError, A]    

def makeJsonRequest(requestData: RequestData): Result[String] = ...

def invoke(url: URL, jsonRequest: String): Result[String] = ...

def parseJsonResponse(jsonResponse: String): Result[ResponseData] = ...
```

I can combine them to write a new function:

```
def invokeService(url: URL, requestData: RequestData) Result[ResponseData] = for {
   jsonRequest <- makeJsonRequest(requestData).right
   jsonResponse <- invoke(url, req).right 
   responseData <- parseJsonResponse(jsonResponse).right
} yield responseData
```

Now what if `parseJsonResponse` fails ?

I get the error but I need also the whole *context*. That is I need `url`, `requestData`, and `jsonRequest`. How would you suggest me do it ?

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but you can map over the left side of the either with `.left.map(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to ask another question about it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a specific case I would make `MyError` into a trait (ADT), and allow one of the possible values to be `JsonParsingFailed(jsonRequest, ...)`.

If it's something more generic I might use `Writer` (or rather `type MyWriter[A] = Writer[Vector[MyLogEntry], A]` and then use `EitherT[MyWriter, MyError, A]`) to "log the event" at every stage.

Comment: Thanks. I am more interested in a generic solution. However I would   prefer to store the "execution context" (t.e. the variables in the scope) in memory instead of writing them to log.

Comment: You are - `Writer` stores data in memory, unless and until you do something else with it. Sadly I don't think there's a generic way to store "everything in scope", you'll have to capture the important things manually.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again. I will probably re-phrase this question to make it more clear (and get more replies :))